# Difficulty in understanding the proof of open mapping theorem and maximum modulus principle

Tags: complex-analysis

It was taken from *Complex Analysis (Princeton Lectures in Analysis, No. 2)* by Elias M. Stein and Rami Shakarchi page 92.

This is the rough idea of the proof of open mapping theorem:

Theorem: If $f$ is non-constant  holomorphic function in a region $\Omega$, then $f$ is open.

Let $w_0$ belong to the image of $f$, say $w_0=f(z_0)$. We must prove that all points $w$ near $w_0$ also belongs to the image of f. Define $g(z) = f(z) - w$. Choose $\delta \gt 0 $ s.t. the disc $|z-z_0| \lt \delta$ is contained the the domain $\Omega$. Then at the end it proves that $g$ has a zero inside the circle $|z-z_0| = \delta$.

Why is it the end of the proof? Can someone elaborate a little bit more?

And this is the rough idea of the proof of maximum modulus principle:

Theorem: If $f$ is non-constant  holomorphic function in a region $\Omega$, then $f$ cannot attain a maximum in $\Omega$.

Suppose that $f$ did attain a maximum at $z_0$. Since $f$ is
holomorphic it is an open mapping, and therefore, if $D \subset \Omega $ is a small disc centered at $z_0$, its image $f(D)$ is open and contains $f(z_0)$. This proves
that there are points in $z \in D$ such that $|f(z)| \gt |f(z_0)|$, a contradiction.

How comes there are points in $z \in D$ such that $|f(z)| \gt |f(z_0)|$? Did I miss some basic stuffs?

Comment: First, you want to prove the image is open. So take $w_0$ and prove all points near $w_0$ are in the image. Second, you have an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ containing $f(z_0)$, so clearly there are points with higher absolute value than $f(z_0)$ (imagine a ball)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $g$ has a zero in the disc $D=\{z:|z-z_0|<\delta\}$, then there is $z\in D$
with $f(z)=w$. This means that if $z$ is "near" to $w_0$, say in
an $\varepsilon$-neighbourhood $U=\{w:|w-w_0|<\varepsilon\}$ then $w\in f(D)$. This means that $U\subseteq f(D)\subseteq f(\Omega)$. Therefore
$f(\Omega)$ is a neighbourhood of each of its points, and so is open.

For the last question, split into cases $f(z_0)=0$ and $f(z_0)\ne0$.
For the first case, you only need that $f$ takes nonzero values near $z_0$.
In the second case you have $f(z_0)(1+\varepsilon)\in f(D)$ for small
positive $\varepsilon$.

Comment: "In the second case you have $f(z_0)(1+\varepsilon)\in f(D)$", does that mean I just have to take the first order approximation of $f$ and consider its absolute value?

Comment: @mathshungry I don't think that's what I meant.... Note that this number is $f(z_0)+\epsilon f(z_0)$ and for small enough $\epsilon$ this is in the image of $\Omega$ under $f$.